# Research proposal and research project

Tags: publications, research-process, research-undergraduate, data

I'm an undergraduate student
I wrote in my research proposal that is was going to divide the outcome variable into mild, moderate but now when I'm writing my research project I found that I have to divide into another additional group which is severe, which in this case will be 3 groups.

Do I have to say in my research project why I chose to divide into severe group as well? For example

I should say like this:
We decided to divide into another additional group which is severe, we changed the method because we found that it's necessary to divide into this group as well.

Or I should just write we will divide into mild, moderate and severe without mentioning what we wrote in research proposal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposal was based on early estimates of the likely outcome. That may have been quite informal and even naive. But the research showed that there is a likely broader range of outcomes.

The best report should mention the history, giving the original hypothesis and, perhaps why you chose to state it that way. Then you write about how the actual data didn't fit that scenario and that it had to be modified.

The complete picture can be valuable to a reader. As an undergraduate the analysis can also be valuable to your own understanding.

Another reason for doing it that way is to avoid a charge of fitting the hypotheses to the data, rather than validating/refuting the hypotheses with the data. Leaving out the early conception is a bit too pat.

An extreme position might even require that you revalidate a new hypothesis on new data. This would be necessary if the data was gathered under invalid assumptions driven by the original hypothesis. But for undergraduate research that is likely overkill. But it might be needed in some studies that have policy implications or implications about health and such.

And, your professor probably has good advice for you, given that they know a bit more about the project.

Comment: thank you very much for your response.

Comment: sir is it good if I write it this way: in our research proposal we divided into mild and moderate but we decided to evaluate the students who are at severe group as well. So we divide the groups into mild, moderate and severe.

Comment: You might be better saying a bit about why you made the change.

Comment: thank you, but I have as well to mention the word proposal ?